# Undefinition of MSVC definition _MBCS and definition of _UNICODE not possible calling cmake from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I want to generate a visual studio project 2010 with cmake from a CMakeLists.txt. Basically this works fine. However, one detail lead to my following observation:

The default character set for the generated visual studio project is 'Multibyte Character'. I want to change it to Unicode. As far as I found out, I need to define either `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE`, but I also need to undefine `_MBCS`. This works out, if I put it in the CMakeLists.txt, but I can't get it working, if I want to set these definitions by command line:

CMakeList.txt, works fine:

```
add_definitions ( -D_UNICODE )
remove_definitions ( -D_MBCS )
```

Command line, definitions are ignored by cmake, if I do it like this:

```
cmake -D_UNICODE="" -U_MBCS=""
```

Command line, definitions are ignored by cmake, if I do it like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT="-D_UNICODE -U_MBCS"
```

I assumed that both ways are the same, but obviously the handling of the definitions from command line is different. I am doing something wrong or is it only possible by using **add_definitions** / **remove_definitions** ?

By the way, I'm using cmake 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

The `-D` flags passed to `cmake` are completely unrelated to the `-D` flags passed to the compiler. See [cmake(1)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options). In short, `cmake -DVARIABLE=VALUE ...` is roughly equivalent to using [`set(VARIABLE VALUE CACHE STRING "")`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) inside your CMakeLists.txt.

If you cannot use `add_definitions` or [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html), you can still pass flags to the compiler by setting [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html) the first time you invoke cmake or by changing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` on later invocations of cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT="-D_UNICODE -U_MBCS" ...
```

Comment: Ok, I see that it is unrelated. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT looks promising for me. I will try it. I'm not sure, if I need to set -D_MBCS or if I need to unset it with -U_MBCS.

Comment: It does not work with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT. But it works with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.